# Unable to use curl despite it appears enabled

Tags: php, curl, command-line, cmd, xampp

I am using `xampp` on Windows 8 ,`curl` appears to be enabled in my PHP configuration but still when I write this in `cmd`

```
curl www.example.com
```

I get this error :
`'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I am also getting the same error even if I use the `shell`provided by xampp.

I have checked `php.ini` and nothing is commented there which could effect curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `cURL` to your path.

Right now, cURL is probably not installed if you can only use it as a php extension.So you would have to install it (see below).

To add something to your path, http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml should help. (its the first link off google).

Edit:
After more looking around, it seems it doesn't matter if cURL is installed in php, you wouldn't be able to use it from your command line. For that, you would need to install cURL for command line use. Check http://guides.instructure.com/s/2204/m/4214/l/83393-how-do-i-install-and-use-curl-on-a-windows-machine for instructions.